# Is Gmail a Single page application

Tags: javascript, gmail, single-page-application

Today I was going through the my mail box. I just seen that when I am navigating through different folders after # that folder name is changing and data being refreshed. I just want to confirm is Gmail a single page application. I also want to develop a mail box kind of application using Single page application concept. Below is sample URL for inbox folder.

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox

Can I develop sample mail box application using angular js as angular js supports concept of SPA?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/) is a single-page application.

That is the reason before loading Gmail you see a progress bar, as it fetches everything from server once and then all the rendering is done on the client side with calls to server only for fetching data and not the DOM.

[image]

Apart from Gmail, other services in the suite like Google Calendar, Google Drive etc. are also Single Page Applications.